# How to read the XML response from SharePoint REST api call

Tags: c#, xml, rest, sharepoint, httpresponse

I am getting XML response for REST call which includes multiple *subnodes* for each entry. Basically any `Lookup` field or `User` field results in a *subnode*. 
Can anybody help me to understand how to read these *subnodes*? As the element name is `Id` or `Email` which is repetitive. Sorry for the very long XML but this is a result of fetching only 2 items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://ppespcollab.amat.com/sites/SSAS/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>f7f3e0d8-73aa-4bd9-a11c-c8d2c884895c</id>
    <title />
    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;5&quot;">
        <id>Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)</id>
        <category term="SP.Data.RequestsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Name" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Name" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/Name">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>d724a6a3-c532-4f43-baaf-f3a25bbaccca</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">31210</d:Id>
                            <d:EMail>Ishan_Halarnkar@contractor.amat.com</d:EMail>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Segment" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Segment" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/Segment">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>9d4306ec-4b01-4624-984b-79445b9d2ec1</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.SegmentsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Title>Test - TechM</d:Title>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">10</d:Id>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/BU" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="BU" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/BU">
            <m:inline>
                <feed>
                    <id>7d3cf6e4-9fdc-4c21-90e9-5112b963dc49</id>
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <entry>
                        <id>44c3ff84-4650-4d85-a6dc-908639338be4</id>
                        <category term="SP.Data.Business_x0020_UnitsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                        <title />
                        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                        <author>
                            <name />
                        </author>
                        <content type="application/xml">
                            <m:properties>
                                <d:Title>CMP</d:Title>
                                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">14</d:Id>
                            </m:properties>
                        </content>
                    </entry>
                </feed>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Author0" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Author0" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/Author0">
            <m:inline>
                <feed>
                    <id>0f399745-10f4-40f0-be4e-1f9d69222d49</id>
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <entry>
                        <id>4c0509ce-62c4-4e90-9689-134b145b02a0</id>
                        <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                        <title />
                        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                        <author>
                            <name />
                        </author>
                        <content type="application/xml">
                            <m:properties>
                                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">31210</d:Id>
                                <d:EMail>Ishan_Halarnkar@contractor.amat.com</d:EMail>
                            </m:properties>
                        </content>
                    </entry>
                </feed>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CC_x0020_List" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CC_x0020_List" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/CC_x0020_List" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Publication_x0020_Type" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Publication_x0020_Type" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(160)/Publication_x0020_Type">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>a002d855-e51b-4f4f-b8ec-3725cf4aecb9</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.Publication_x0020_TypeListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Title>Presentation</d:Title>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <title />
        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">160</d:Id>
                <d:Title>asssfsfdsf</d:Title>
                <d:End_x0020_Use>BLR</d:End_x0020_Use>
                <d:Approval_x0020_Type>Parallel</d:Approval_x0020_Type>
                <d:Due_x0020_Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-09-26T05:00:00Z</d:Due_x0020_Date>
                <d:Description>sdfssfsfssf</d:Description>
                <d:Status>Submitted</d:Status>
                <d:History>Request submitted by Ishan Halarnkar --CNTR on Wednesday, September 13, 2017 8&amp;#58;15 AM&lt;/br&gt;</d:History>
                <d:RequestID>2017_00000160</d:RequestID>
                <d:EndUseYear>2014</d:EndUseYear>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">160</d:ID>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry m:etag="&quot;7&quot;">
        <id>Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)</id>
        <category term="SP.Data.RequestsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Name" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Name" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/Name">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>b76cc22b-f985-444a-873a-46ae2cd0a10a</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6760</d:Id>
                            <d:EMail>Denise_Schmidt@amat.com</d:EMail>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Segment" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Segment" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/Segment">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>6e70b80b-fff6-4662-8f53-26fc977f34ef</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.SegmentsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Title>Testing Segment 0917</d:Title>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">11</d:Id>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/BU" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="BU" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/BU">
            <m:inline>
                <feed>
                    <id>f5e5e76d-07b7-442f-b6bf-73d9ed65e708</id>
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <entry>
                        <id>07bd9eed-23f7-4b10-8f38-42e0845f19ca</id>
                        <category term="SP.Data.Business_x0020_UnitsListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                        <title />
                        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                        <author>
                            <name />
                        </author>
                        <content type="application/xml">
                            <m:properties>
                                <d:Title>ds Testing</d:Title>
                                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">24</d:Id>
                            </m:properties>
                        </content>
                    </entry>
                </feed>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Author0" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Author0" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/Author0">
            <m:inline>
                <feed>
                    <id>717cf9a2-9f0a-4265-bb32-1c90989ba6ed</id>
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <entry>
                        <id>4c593a4e-5c2e-4f1a-8c99-cb2d81b33af3</id>
                        <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                        <title />
                        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                        <author>
                            <name />
                        </author>
                        <content type="application/xml">
                            <m:properties>
                                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6760</d:Id>
                                <d:EMail>Denise_Schmidt@amat.com</d:EMail>
                            </m:properties>
                        </content>
                    </entry>
                </feed>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CC_x0020_List" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CC_x0020_List" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/CC_x0020_List" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Publication_x0020_Type" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Publication_x0020_Type" href="Web/Lists(guid'16b26978-b5d8-407a-a82d-e66017158895')/Items(159)/Publication_x0020_Type">
            <m:inline>
                <entry>
                    <id>62f94289-1e4b-4e83-94fe-1f518bde639b</id>
                    <category term="SP.Data.Publication_x0020_TypeListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                    <title />
                    <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
                    <author>
                        <name />
                    </author>
                    <content type="application/xml">
                        <m:properties>
                            <d:Title>Presentation</d:Title>
                            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
                        </m:properties>
                    </content>
                </entry>
            </m:inline>
        </link>
        <title />
        <updated>2017-09-14T09:51:55Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">159</d:Id>
                <d:Title>Test on 9/12/17</d:Title>
                <d:End_x0020_Use>TPAS</d:End_x0020_Use>
                <d:Approval_x0020_Type>Parallel</d:Approval_x0020_Type>
                <d:Due_x0020_Date m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-09-28T05:00:00Z</d:Due_x0020_Date>
                <d:Description>testing email notices</d:Description>
                <d:Status>Submitted</d:Status>
                <d:History>Request delegated by Denise Schmidt (ds Testing - CTO) on Tuesday, September 12, 2017 2&amp;#58;16 PM&lt;/br&gt;Request approved by Denise Schmidt (ds Testing - Manager) on Tuesday, September 12, 2017 2&amp;#58;15 PM&lt;/br&gt;Request submitted by Denise Schmidt on Tuesday, September 12, 2017 2&amp;#58;12 PM&lt;/br&gt;</d:History>
                <d:RequestID>2017_00000159</d:RequestID>
                <d:EndUseYear m:null="true" />
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">159</d:ID>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

The code i am using is but is not giving the expected results :

```
XmlDocument listXml = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager xmlnspm = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            xmlnspm.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
            xmlnspm.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
            xmlnspm.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
            listXml.LoadXml(response);
            var prop = listXml.SelectNodes("//atom:entry/atom:content/m:properties", xmlnspm);
            List<string> sdsd = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlNode ndlist in prop)

            {

                sdsd.Add(ndlist.SelectSingleNode("d:Id", xmlnspm).InnerXml +
                    ndlist.SelectSingleNode("d:EMail", xmlnspm).InnerXml +
                     ndlist.SelectSingleNode("d:Status", xmlnspm).InnerXml+
                     ndlist.SelectSingleNode("d:History", xmlnspm).InnerXml);
            }
```

The result i am looking for is :
For each entry, read the

1. If Name then Name(Id and Email)
2. If Segment then Segment(Title and Id)
3. If BU then BU(Title and Id)
4. If Author0 then Author0(Id and Email)
   ...likewise for all subnodes
   and for all main nodes i need the value
5. Id
6. Title
7. End_x0020_Use
8. Approval_x0020_Type

Is there any way to Serialize this data in a more readable format or i'l have to loop each and every node?
Please suggest the best option as i don't have much experience in XML data.

Comment: If the XML structure is pretty rigid and doesn't change then yes you can deserialize it into a strongly typed class.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static List<XElement> nodes;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement feed = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = feed.GetDefaultNamespace();
            foreach (XElement entry in feed.Elements(ns + "entry"))
            {
                Entry newEntry = new Entry();
                Entry.entries.Add(newEntry);

                newEntry.title = (string)entry.Element(ns + "title");
                newEntry.end_x0020_Use = (string)entry.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "End_x0020_Use").FirstOrDefault();
                newEntry.approval_x0020_Type = (string)entry.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Approval_x0020_Type").FirstOrDefault();

                newEntry.links = entry.Elements(ns + "link").Select(x => x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "entry").Select(y => new Link() {
                   name = (string)y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "name").FirstOrDefault(),
                   id = (string)y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "id").FirstOrDefault(),
                   email = (string)y.Descendants().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "EMail").FirstOrDefault(),
                   title = (string)x.Attributes().Where(z => z.Name.LocalName == "title").FirstOrDefault()
                }).FirstOrDefault()
                ).ToList();
            }

        }

    }
    public class Entry
    {
        public static List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

        public string title { get; set;}
        public string end_x0020_Use { get; set; }
        public string approval_x0020_Type { get; set; }
        public List<Link> links { get; set; }

    }
    public class Link
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use `$filter` in your REST API call so that you would get a JSON result which is pretty much easy to work with. The XML retrieval may fail sometimes.